# Function contains a loop which doesn't work when an input contains a non-integer char

Tags: c

i have this function in my project:

```
void inputIntArray(int array[], int size){
j = size;
for(i=0;i<j;i++){
    printf("* Enter number #%d out of %d: ",(i+1),j);
    scanf("%d",&k);
    array[i] = k;
    }
}
```

It's supposed to fill an array, and works fine when integers are input,
when something which is not an integer is being inputted it will just fill the remaining cells in the array with the last integer inputted and skip the whole project while only printing everything remaining...

Anyone knows what causes this error? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
After changing to:

```
void inputIntArray(int array[], int size){
    int i = 0,j = 0,k = 0;
    j = size;
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("* Enter number #%d out of %d: ",(i+1),j);
        if(scanf("%d",&k) != 1){
            break;
        }
        array[i] = k;
    }
}
```

I'm still experiencing the same error.....

Comment: The return value of `scanf` is the number of successfully read inputs. If you check that, you can act appropriately. You're expecting 1, if you don't get that, do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect it to do if a non-integer is used as the input? It doesn't seem like it's an error skipping non-integer input, but the correct behavior. If you want it to keep working, you need to handle that error by checking what the user inputs. If the input is not what the program expects, it's up to the coder to resolve that or you'll get unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is the fact that your `array` is of type `int`.  If you want some other type, you'll have to have an array of that type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `scanf()` fails.  If it does, because invalid data was entered, you have to flush the `stdin` buffer and repeat the `scanf()` again.

Answer (score 0):

The format specifier %d tells scanf to expect an integer. See e.g. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf).